# How to unsubscribe from post request?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have simple post request, that I use to create messages. **The problem** is that the function sendMessage() will work **the same way forever**, sending the same message into DB even after I change "message" param until I destroy the table. The way I thaught to solve the problem was to unsubscribe immediately after request, but it seems that I do it wrong, cause message even does not appear into Db. Or the solution is completely different. I also wanted to use observer.complete() or something like that, but have no idea how to use lambda expression not in the new Observable, but into create() method.

Will be grateful for any help, new into Ng.

service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  private url = environment.apiUrl + '/message';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public create(request: CreateMessageRequest): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.post<void>(this.url, request);
  }
}
```

function

```
public sendMessage(message: string){
    let request: CreateMessageRequest = {
      Message:  message, 
    }
    const req = this.messageService.create(request).subscribe();
    //req.unsubscribe();
  }
```

P.S.:

html. "test" is " " at the start and definitely plays no role here (I suppose).

```
 <form>
      <textarea #refVariable [value]="test" type="text" placeholder="Write message"></textarea>
      <button class="buttonTwo" type="submit" (click)="sendMessage(refVariable.value)"></button>
  </form>
```

Comment: This part of the code looks ok to me. Could you add the part of the code where you call the `sendMessage` method? // Can you also check in the broswer devtools if you're making one http call or multiple ones?

Comment: @akotech , yes, there are two "Request URL: localhost:5000/api/message" in a row after each function call: red one and black with status code 204. Html added.

Comment: The code still looks ok to me. It's not the most common way to handle form input in angular, but it should work. Have you check the payload of POST requests in the devtools? Are they the same? If they are different, then the problem is in the backend.  // btw the 2 request per click is common for CORS requests.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of unusbscribing from a `Subscription`, but the easiest way for your case will be:

```
class YourComp implements OnDestroy {
 private unusbscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribe.next();
  this.unsubscribe.complete();
}

public sendMessage(message: string) {
  /.../
  this.messageService.create(request)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe();
}
```

Breaking this down will be like:

- `takeUntil` operator waits a notification from the passed observable
- when your component gets destroyed, `ngOnDestroy` will be called, so `this.unsubscribe$.next()` will emit a notification, and after that using `this.unsubscribe.complete()` will complete the `Subject`.
- `takeUntil` will receive the notification from `unsubscribe$` and will complete the stream, and unsubscribe from it.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for me. It still passes the first message.

Comment: Of course it passes the message. You subscribe to it and trigger the post

Comment: I mean, after your solution it passes the SAME first message on each button click, but as you see, in this question I want it to pass the message, and then, after I type another text, after button click pass message with new text.

Comment: My solution unsubscribe from the subscription only when you destroy your component, where this function is used. ( also this is how it’s supposed to be). You want to keep the subscription active while you are using your current component. Unsubscribing from it doesn’t have anything to do with the response from the api